# My Rockshox Froze Hard

Tags: fork, suspension

My Rockshox Dart 3 (Quite an old one, bought from my friend USED) froze in the winter (-15 °C). It won't budge. I thought I turned the lockout but I didn't. Is there any chance that some water got into the forks? Do I need to change the oil inside? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever serviced the fork before now?   What's its approximate mileage?

Comment: well, i bought it from my friend but i don't think he serviced it before. And I don't know the mileage of it. (it was in my friends garage for years though)

Comment: I'd recommend a complete rebuild, and then service it according to the manufacturers recommendation.  For many, that's a service every 30 or 50 hours of active riding, or yearly, whichever is less.   If the rebuild kit costs more than a new fork, then its a wise financial choice to replace.   A rebuild kit will replace all the seals and rubber parts, and all the fluids, and may include replacement springs too.

Comment: You could try sitting on the bike, squeezing the front brake and then rocking your weight back and forward.  This will apply significant force to the fork, and not all directly up/down the shaft.
A quick google suggests a service kit + oil for a Dart is ~£30, although if it is seized this won't help unless you can free it.

Comment: @AndyP well when the temperature is warm enough it works well but when its cold it seizes. i think using the service kit is a good idea! (then i'll have to service it in spring..)